# How to return string array using Pinvoke

Tags: c#, .net, c, arrays, pinvoke

My c/c++ skills are non-existent 
and 
there's some custom string array data that needs to be returned from an old C dll

fyi - The C/C++ code can be modified as needed

Comment: well it either compiles or it doesn't.  There is no such thing as "barely compiles"

Comment: Please provide the definition of the C function.

Comment: The return statement is useful

Comment: the pinvoke bible is http://www.amazon.com/NET-COM-Complete-Interoperability-Guide/dp/067232170X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information about your specific case, it's impossible to say how you'd marshal the return value.  Perhaps this page of interop marshaling samples will help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e765dyyy.aspx

The above link no longer works. Try [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Jaykul: So it seems. The current MSDN pages have a link to that non-existent page. I added a link to the interop marshaling page.